# PowerBi - Getting data to PowerBi Cloud

Tags: powerbi

I am kinda new to PowerBi. I created a report in PowerBi Desktop that gets data from a SQL Server database. I also wrote a stored procedure that will gather the data I need for the report. It pulls 30 or so data points and is about 3 months' worth of historical data. Right now the report imports the data I need to create the visuals (pulling from a local SQL Server).

I would like to have other people view the report I created which means I would like to put this on the cloud. I have been reading up on Microsoft's [page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/connect-data/service-real-time-streaming) and other articles on the internet about real-time streaming, but I am unsure what method is best for me or there another method.

I am leaning towards this [method](https://sqlitybi.com/streaming-data-from-sql-server-to-power-bi-using-powershell/), but I am wondering what others have done. What is the best way to get data to the PowerBi cloud for my situation?

Answer (score 1):

Real-time streaming has nothing to do with your case. Just publish the report to Power BI Service. There are few things to be aware of, though.

The published report (assuming the storage mode is [Import](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/connect-data/service-dataset-modes-understand#import-mode)) will contain the data as per the last refresh in Power BI Desktop. To refresh the data in the service, it must be able to connect to your on-premise SQL Server. The best way to do that is to install [Power BI Data Gateway](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/gateway/) on a server in your network and configure it. Then you can [schedule a refresh](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/connect-data/refresh-scheduled-refresh) (1 time per 24h for Power BI Free account, up to 8 times for Power BI Pro, or up to 48 times a day if the workspace is attached to a Power BI Premium).

To [share](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/collaborate-share/service-share-dashboards) a report in Power BI service, you and all the consumers will need to have a Power BI Pro license. There are ways to share without the need to license all users, like [Publish to web](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/collaborate-share/service-publish-to-web) (Don't do that! First this will make the report **PUBLIC** so anyone can see it, and second you will need an approval from your Power BI admin) and [embedding in an application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/embedded/embed-sample-for-customers) (which requires programming skills).

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you only have to publish the report or dashboard in the power bi service.

Then you can create an app if you have the premium license and give the access to the users or just give the access to the power bi dashboard directly.

As Andrey comments you would need a data gateway to refresh the dataset

Answer (score 0):

You can use SSIS to perform ETL from different SQL data sources.
The SSIS then send data to a Azure SQL Database.
Your PowerBI reports can then access that Azure SQL to import data, apply necessary access control and refresh schedule.